# How to force Weblogic to start deployments in active state (i.e. not just prepared)

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

When I start a Weblogic instance with a deployed application, the deployment is *sometimes* left in prepared state, not in active state.  I have to go to Weblogic Console and start the deployment manually, which is quite slow and annoying repetetive work.  Since this is done on a development machine — sometimes 50 times a day, — there are no security implication as the server is only visible on the local network.  Is there some way to have it always start the deployment active?

Note that I'm not redeploying the application, I instead have it "constantly deployed" and stop/start the Weblogic instance using the scripts in `bin` directory.

Comment: I have the opposite problem. When I start WebLogic with _/startWebLogic.sh_ , all the deployments are started (Active). I want them to stay in "Prepared" state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running weblogic in `development` mode, you can use the autodeploy folder for your app. See details here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/deployment/autodeploy.html#wp1021620

Think this should solve your problem